# If statement not accepting variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
meJi = 33;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: mega,
data: string,
beforeSend: function() {
    $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
},
complete: function() {
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
},
success: function(msg) {
    loading_hide();
    f = (msg).length;
    if (f <= 1250) {
        alert("su busqueda no presenta resultados");
        code(3);

        else {
            $("#container").html(msg);
            fdemandados();
        }
    }
});
function code(ig) {
    console.log(img);
    meJi = ig;
}

$("#select_comprobar3").on('click', function(event) {
    tacuba = $("#amazon").val();
    ca = "2";
    dan = "g";
    if (meJi ==3) {
        avisobusqueda2 = $("#avisofiltro").html("zzzFiltro activado Busqueda por la palabra: " + tacuba + " - clic para quitar ").fadeIn('slow');
    } else {}
    if (!tacuba) {
        alert("Debe ingresar una palabra");
    } else {
        lor = tacuba;
        var page = "1";
        loadData(page, dan, lor);
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

the problem is this:

```
if (meJi==3) {
```

I don't know why but meJi variable never changes to 3 so the conditional always assume that meJi is 33.

**edit: Im change the conditional part but the problem still exist.**

Comment: Do you get the alert "su busqueda no presenta resultados"?

Comment: In this code it will never get to `"3"`, but you are also comparing String with Integer.

Comment: @Niels `"3" == 3`, `"3" !=== 3`

Comment: the else part should be after the if statement, not inside

Comment: @DaveNewton I am aware it returns true, but it's kinda nasty.

Comment: @Niels why would it not get there if it is firing the alert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
function code(ig){
  console.log(img);
  meJi = ig;
}
```

Should it not be `console.log(ig);`?  How you have it would cause an error (with `img` not defined) and therefore, meJi would not get set.

Comment: This would NOT cause an error.  It would just output `undefined` in the console.

Comment: @Orin yes, but this is not the question. Is another mistake.

Comment: @Steve If img is not defined it will throw a `RefereneceError` and prevent meJi from being set.

Comment: @Steve It would throw `ReferenceError: img is not defined` error, not undefined. Unless I missed where it is declared. Meaning it would never set the variable to 3.

Comment: @aug it changes nothing. I am correct that error and the problem still exist.

Comment: @all - Mea culpa - of course you are right... and therefore this is certainly the correct answer to the issue the OP has.

Comment: @Orin you typo'd his typo - the function name is code not cod -- Juan - is the console writing '3' like you expect